# Why a new instance of ViewModel is created after navigation back?

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, viewmodel, android-lifecycle

I'm currently developing an Android application based on **MVVM**, so I'm using the **ViewModel** principle to contain my UI data.

I also know that a **ViewModel** is **linked** to its **owner** and that it was destroyed when the owner is destroyed. (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel).

[image]

My problem occurs between Fragment A and B (visible on the image above).

My Fragment A contains a recyclerview which, when I click on the element, directs me to Fragment B using the component navigation (see example below).

```
view?.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.action_commandListFragment_to_commandDetailsFragment)
```

My fragment B initializes the "CommandDetailViewModel" using the ViewModelProvider and its sub fragment (C & D) retrieves it by passing "requireParentFragment()" as argument of the ViewModelProvider.

```
//Fragment B
mviewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(CommandDetailsViewModel::class.java)


//Fragment C & D
mparentViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireParentFragment()).get(CommandDetailsViewModel::class.java)
```

If I click on a button on fragment D, I go back to fragment A, always using the controller navigation.

```
//In Fragment B
mviewModel.mCurrentCommandFinished.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        if(it){
            view?.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.action_commandDetailsFragment_to_commandListFragment)
        }
    })
```

So far I understand, but I realized that I was doing something wrong, indeed, this return to fragment A does this because a boolean LiveData of the ViewModel changes to "true" and is therefore left to "true", even after navigation.

I was expecting to have a problem when I click on Item 1, the variable being as true I would have been immediately put back on my list but it is not the case, a new ViewModel is created so the value is set to false (default one) and I don't understand why.

Does the navigation have the effect of **completely destroying** fragment B and thus the associated viewModel ?

Because I don't understand why a new instance of the viewModel is created each time I click on my element while my child fragments manage to get the previously created instance.

**NB:** The viewModel affection are done in "onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)" in fragment B, C & D.

**EDIT :** I tried to put a log in the override "onDestroy()" function of Fragment B and I discover that the fragment wasn't destroy & his VM neither.

The problem is that I recreated a new instance of my fragment with

```
view?.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.action_commandListFragment_to_commandDetailsFragment)
```

Is there a way to retrieve the "original" instance or destroyed it ?

**EDIT 2 :** It was my fault, I don't exploit the "popUpTo" & "popUpToInclusive" variables on the action from Fragment B to Fragment A, so my fragment B was still in stack but not used anymore, now it's destroyed properly (https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate)

Comment: ViewModel is not a singleton and you are expecting it to be one, a new instance of the ViewModel is created for each activity

Comment: Ok so, when my fragments C & D get their VM, they get the instance of the "current" parent thanks to the requestParentFragment() passed in ViewModelProvider ? And so the navigation component destroy the fragment instance and do not let it in the back Stack ?